# the jquery fuction is not work on the click button?

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

```
<button " name="news_name" onClick="news()">news</button>
```

if I use the jquery function

```
<script Language="JavaScript"> 
$(function () {
 function news(){
console.log('news is going');
}
})

</script>
```

it shows the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:news is not defined at news(...)
at HTMLBUttonElement,onlick(....)
```

If I not use the jquery

```
<script Language="JavaScript"> 
 function news(){
console.log('news is going');
}

</script>
```

it works well!

I don't know why cannot use the

```
$(function () {
})
```

And if it's right.I cannot use the jquery on my script.how can I fix the problem?

Comment: `console.log('news is going');` <- Try. You have to wrap text with `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var news=null;

$(function(){
     news=function(){
            console.log('news is going');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button name="news_name" onClick="news()">news</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline `onClick` can only access global objects. You also mis-spelled `function` in `fuction news()`

When you declare the function inside `$(function()` it is within a closure and not available in global(window) scope

Generally it is better practice not to use inline event handlers and since you are using jQuery can easily add an event listener unobtrusively

```js
function news(){
  console.log('news is going');
}

$(function(){
  $('button[name="news_name"]').click(news)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="news_name">news</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your clearly explaination. It can only access global objects that's the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `script` tags should be small case and the `attributes` too you are starting with `<Script>` and ending with `</script>` which does not close the tag.

The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, and should not be used. When W3C was working on `HTML5`, they discovered all browsers have `"text/javascript"` as the default script `type`, so they standardized it to be the default value.

Just use `<script></script>` or `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` if you like to.

Then as mentioned in the comments by `@Eddie` you are not wrapping the text in the quotes inside the `console.log()`

use like

```js
function news() {
  console.log('news is going');
}
$("#news_name").on('click', news);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="news_name" id="news_name">news</button>
```

Comment: Is <button " name="news_name" onClick="news()">news</button> still?
It will work as the function news() is in,not the jquery news() function?

Comment: @robspin i added the button too see the answer i updated it

Answer (score 0):

Please use input type button and set Id of button then -

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){


alert('ok');

})
```